# Do thing after div loaded content. .load() function

Tags: html, loaded

```
$(".test").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();     
    var self = this;

    $("#preloader #image").fadeIn();
    $("#preloader").fadeIn();

    $(".frame").load(self.href,function() { 

        $("#preloader #image").fadeOut();
        $("#preloader").delay(111).fadeOut();

        $(".content").slideToggle(185);
    });
});
```

This should slideToggle after load content of div('.frame'), but content slide instantly, also content appear faster than preloader fadeOut. Why is this happening?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Well, it's not exactly your first time. Please make sure to have a properly indented code, it's way easier to read for potential answerers.

Comment: code is indented properly. I dont know whats going on. Help